# How to set the value of a select_tag widget in ruby using its symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a `select_tag` widget, much like the following:

```
= select_tag :setup_form_popup, options_for_select([ ["No Setup Time","0"],["15 Minute", "15"], ["30 Minute", "30"], ["45 Minute", "45"], ["60 Minute", "60"], ["75 Minute", "75"], ["90 Minute","90"], ["105 Minute", "105"],["120 Minute","120"]], @event.setup_time), {:prompt => 'Setup Time'}
```

How would I set the value of a `select_tag` widget using its symbol?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify. What do you mean by symbol--the id of the element? What do you mean by set the value--the default value or changing it after the fact?

Assuming you mean you want to change which item is selected in the select element, then

- You're already setting a default value in `options_for_select`. Change that if you want something else.
- You can use JS to dynamically change the values of your option tags. Assuming you're using a selector, that's where you can pass in the "symbol" (the name, id, or class, or whatever you'd like).

But really it could be anything without you clarifying further.

Comment: Yea so I am trying to change the selected value of the form after the fact ... as it is always going to the default after I update. The situation is I need the default to render when the page loads, but I am using ajax to update, and while the form updates the DB, the selected option always returns to it's default even though that select_tag form is not in sync with ajax

Comment: So the code in `@event.setup_time` only executes on the first page load--it won't change by itself without you using JS to alter the element (it's not like there's going to be Ruby in your page source).

I'm a little confused why you'd need to do this, since presumably your user could just...use the form and change the selected value, but I'm guessing you have some other way of processing the form. In that case, you'll need JS.

Comment: Also, are you talking about reloading the page after the user submits the form? If the default value isn't as expected even then, then it implies that `@event.setup_time` isn't what you think it is, or the change to `@event.setup_time` hasn't persisted in the DB like you think.

Comment: The db is not the issue, have been monitoring that religiously

Comment: All I am trying to do is set the setup time once a new value is selected ... for some reason the form is not displaying the freshly selected option

Comment: Have been hashing out stuff in JQuery, but I think the way my code is setup that might not be an option, or it might not sure a bit new to this. Is there a way to set the setup time through ruby? For example, saying something like  setup_form_popup.val(15).change() in ruby

Comment: Right, but like I said, `@event.setup_time` won't change unless you reload the page. Are you reloading the page? If you don't want to have to, you need JS; if you are reloading the page (after changing the value), the DB value is changing, and you're still not getting the right default, you might simply not be loading `@event` properly.

Comment: `setup_form_popup.val(15).change()` is definitely not something that exists in ruby. Ruby's not a web framework, it's not like JQuery where you have code "loaded" in the webpage. All Rails is doing is processing your code and then generating some static web pages for you; you can't touch those pages with Ruby after they get served.

Comment: Exactly, I am not reloading the page .. using ajax to update parts of the page which respond with the setup time. Only thing that is not responding is the selected option for the select_tag

Comment: Alright, so yea if that's not feasible to do in ruby I'll focus on the jquery of it

Comment: Then this is a JS error, and you need to write JS to appropriately take whatever values you got back from your DB with Ajax, and then spread them to your select element.

Comment: program works perfectly when I run setup_form_popup.val(15).change(), having trouble with the variables

Comment: Great--if your Ruby issue is resolved, can you mark this question as closed?

Comment: Data was just being cached in the website ... everything good now